# TileProvider (UrlTileProvider) and googlemaps to only allow zooming for tiles available on the device

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a process where users can push a set of tiles to their device from my server for a given location area so they can view them while offline.  Some of the tile sets however have limited zoom capabilities, for illustration's sake let's say from 8 to 12.

I would like to limit the google map zooming while in a location that only has 8-12 zoom levels to those levels so that users can't zoom beyond the available tiles and just see the blank grid.

I've searched SO and google and haven't gotten any hits with what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm sure I could work something up myself but thought I'd ask here first to see if anyone has written this logic already and would be willing to share.

If not, some suggestions about where to plug this in would also be appreciated so I can start it on my own.

I'm actually working on a xamarin project right now so having to use an extended UrlTileProvider instead of a regular TileProvider.

any samples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: If there are no tiles for a level then what is the problem? Zooming is not possible then. Well the user could come on that level. Ok. But why is that a problem? What would he see? A grid?

Comment: the problem is from a UX standpoint.  some of the users who will be using this app are not tech savvy...like AT ALL.  If they see a grid they won't know what to do with themselves and this app will be used for navigation in very remote areas.

Comment: Well i would feel desparate if im in a remote area using your app and i could always zoom to level 14 and suddenly it goes only to 12.

Comment: You could much better display a default tile with text "sorry google does not supply tiles for this zoom level use openstreetmap instead" ;-).

Comment: `If they see a grid they won't know what to do with themselves `. Sorry i do not believe that. They know they use off line cards. And will have downloaded tiles before they left and will have tried them out off line before. They will have seen it already. They will have seen an empty grid and realized what was on.

Comment: It is the same if they are on level 11 but move outside the region for which tiles are downloaded. They will then see empty squares. Let them!